# Windows RDP Clipboard Syncing Stops Working Occasionally - Permanent Fix?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, windows-server, rdp, windows-server-2019

I've been facing a persistent problem with clipboard synchronization in Windows RDP sessions. Occasionally, it seems like the RDP server stops responding to clipboard requests, making it impossible to copy or paste data between the local and remote machine.

**Temporary Fix I've Found:**
As a workaround, I log into the Administrative user on the remote machine, copy the text, and paste it into Notepad. This seems to jumpstart the clipboard sync again. However, resorting to this fix frequently is frustrating.

Has anyone else encountered this issue? More importantly, is there a permanent solution to this problem?

Comment: You can install FreeClipViewer.exe on the RDP server to view the clipboard, and you need to confirm if your Ctrl-C shortcut key is not working